# Logback - determine the actual logger that sent the log message to an appender

Tags: java, logging, logback

Is it possible to determine the actual logger which sends log messages to an appender in [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)? Example:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <logger name="com.example">
      <appender-ref ref="myAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.example.sub">
      <appender-ref ref="myAppender"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Now both `com.example` and `com.example.sub` hold references to `myAppender`. If I log to `com.example.sub.MyClass` both loggers would trigger [`.doAppend()`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/Appender.html#doAppend%28E%29) on `myAppender`. Now, is it possible to get the name of the logger that actually sent the message (holding the reference to `myAppender`)?

Exemplary output:

```
Logger com.example (com.example.sub.MyClass)  Test
Logger com.example.sub (com.example.sub.MyClass)  Test
```

I'm configuring the logging framework programmatically. I thought, I could do something like

```
ContextSelectorStaticBinder binder = ContextSelectorStaticBinder.getSingleton();
ContextSelector selector = binder.getContextSelector();
selector.getLoggerContext(name).setName(name);
selector.getLoggerContext(name).getLogger(name).addAppender(appender);
```

And then later in the `Encoder`:

```
@Override
public void doEncode(ILoggingEvent event) throws IOException {
    String name = event.getLoggerContextVO().getName();
    // ...
}
```

But `selector.getLoggerContext(name)` doesn't return different instances. Background: I have one appender that sends log messages to a WebSocket. This appender should be able to "subscribe" to different loggers (basically like in the XML). The webpage would present the log messages in different tabs ("channels").

Answer (score 0):

You can know which logger/class logs with layouts : http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord

You may filter logs with a custom pattern to show them in different tabs.

Comment: No, `%logger` returns `com.example.sub.MyClass`, `%contextName` returns `default`. I need `com.example` and `com.example.sub`. I also can't filter since these values are missing.